# How could I inspect fields and values of any object by anything else excepting `toString()` in Java?

Tags: java, tostring

Does method `toString()` is convenient for inspecting objects?
What are alternatives to `toString()`?
Could you provide some simple snippets for logging objects in Java? Are they possible without `reflection`?

Comment: You either use a toString() assuming it has a sane implementation or you use reflection directly or indirectly.  You could define your own interface for all your objects but this is more complex.

Comment: It would be easier to recommend something with some more context. For logging purposes, toString() method should be good enough in most cases or if the information is not sufficient - assemble it yourself using data obtained from getters. But if you need it for proper debugging session... just use a debugger in the IDE ;).

Comment: `toString()` is a text representation of an object, its all up to certain class implementation how `toString()` output will look like

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested by the commenters already, you might want to **use a debugger** (most easily the one from your IDE). though it is not clear by your question what you need it for.
Using a debugger lets you access all the information of an object, but also just the information you are interested in, of a particular object of a particular type at a particular moment.
`toString()` does not and should not give you all the information an object entails.